# Docker container can't mount folder

Tags: docker, volume, mount

I am working on an application. Using NodeJS for language and docker docker-compose for deployment.

I have an endpoint for uploading files. When i upload a file application keeps it at the "files" folder (files folder is at the root of the project). When container restarts i dont want to loose files, so i created a volume named "myfiles" and mounted it to "/files" path.

**But when i check the myfiles volume path i dont see any of the created files by api. And if i restart the container uploaded files disappears.**

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file for api

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  api:
    image: api-image
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - myfiles:/files
volumes:
  myfiles:
```

After `docker-compose up -d` i upload some files and see them in container by calling

`docker exec -it container_name ls
files     node_modules       package.json
index.js  package-lock.json  src`

`docker exec -it container_name ls files
d5a3455a39d8185153308332ca050ad8.png`

Files created succesfully.

I checked if container mounts correctly by
`docker inspect container_name` and result:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myfiles/_data",
            "Destination": "/files",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rslave"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you give an absolute path to volumes such as `- /absolute/path/to/myfiles:/files`

Comment: I gave the absolute path of myfiles volume. "/var/lib/docker/volumes/bpmfiles/_data" Same result.

Comment: How are you stopping and restarting your containers?  The [docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) documentation suggests that named volumes declared in the YAML file should be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating volume, you are not using folder. Try to use folder `myfiles` from current directory:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  api:
    image: api-image
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./myfiles:/files
```

Comment: I tried what you said and get the same result. Here is the docker inspect container result

`"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/root/bpm-project/myfiles",
                "Destination": "/files",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ]`

Comment: They are not the same. Now you are using local folder myfiles (/root/bpm-project/myfiles), before it was a docker volume myfiles (/var/lib/docker/volumes/myfiles/_data). Upload files into /files not files in the container - use an absolute path in the container.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my NodeJS code to use absolute path and it worked. Here what i did

// server.js
`app.use('/files', express.static('/files'))`

//files.js
`const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/files')
  }
})
`